# Error in \setmainfont

Tags: fonts, xetex, errors, fontspec

I'm trying to follow the example on the [Wikipedia page about XeTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XeTeX#Example).
But when I run the TeX code, I get this error:

```
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/fixltx2e.sty))kpathsea: Invalid fontname `Linux Libertine O', contains ' '

! Font \zf@basefont="Linux Libertine O" at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found.
\zf@fontspec ...ntname \zf@suffix " at \f@size pt 
                                              \unless \ifzf@icu \zf@set@...
l.3 ...infont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}
```

Any idea why that is? I have both the TTF files for Libertine installed and I also have the XeTeX libertine package.

[EDIT] I'm on openSUSE 11.3 and I've installed XeTeX from the TeX Live 2010 CD.

Comment: Could we have a clue as to your OS and _where_ you've installed the font.

Comment: openSUSE 11.3 and I've installed xetex from the TeXlife 2010 CD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TTF version of Libertine are usually named 'Linux Libertine' without the trailing ' O', so try using that name or installing the OTF version.

Answer (score 1):

Open the font with font viewer such as `gfontview`, is the font name in the correct format?

Ensure that the font by this (correct) name is accessible in other program such as open office!

Comment: What "font manager" are you talking about?

Comment: @Aaron: I mean a font viewer such as `gfontview`, which show the correct font name on up right hand side of its window.